# What does "maybe" mean in Sega Rally?

Tags: sega-rally

In Sega Rally some corners are described with the word "maybe", e.g. "easy right maybe".

What does this mean in the game?

Answer (score 5):

In rally racing pacenotes, "maybe", denoted in the pacenotes with a ?, denotes something that lacks confidence and thus is left to the driver to decide how to deal with. This is commonly used to refer to potential weather issues, such as a slippery surface, or decisions that depend on the type and condition of the vehicle.

In the context of the SEGA Rally series, "easy right maybe", indicates a suggested turn difficulty. In this case, the navigator is offering the driver some choice in how much to slow.

Sources:
http://www.jemba.se/notesUSA.htm
https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/arcade/583622-sega-rally-championship/faqs/827